How to Securely Handle File Uploads in a Custom WordPress Plugin?
I'm developing a custom WordPress plugin that allows users to upload files. I need to ensure that the file upload process is secure to avoid vulnerabilities such as directory traversal and file upload attacks. What are the best practices and techniques for securely managing file uploads in my WordPress plugin? Specifically, I'm looking for advice on validating file types, sanitizing file names, setting appropriate permissions, and any other security measures to implement.
I implemented basic file upload functionality in my custom WordPress plugin without specific security measures.
function handle_file_upload() {
    if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $target_dir = $upload_dir['path'];
        $target_file = $target_dir . '/' . basename($_FILES['upload_file']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}

I expected the files to download securely with no vulnerabilities. However, I noticed potential risks such as file upload attacks and unauthorized access due to lack of validation and sanitization.

There is a great article for best practices for file uploads specific to WordPress here that touches on pretty much everything you are asking about
